# How to extract specific number of bytes in a list object in python

Tags: python, list, csv, reverse-engineering, readlines

I have a file separated by semicolons and I need to read this file by parts and so I'm using readlines(*k*), where *k* is a buffer size chosen. The piece of code below not exactly return the '*k*' quantity required because each line could not have the same length of bytes (case of csv files). Something like that :

```
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

f=open(file,'r')
chunck_tmp = f.readlines(BUFFER_SIZE)
```

In this point "*chunck_tmp*" is an list and I would like to discover the exact number of bytes inside it. The problem is that now the information has another format including spaces, brackets and something else to consider if I try something like "str(*chunck_tmp*)" and so the number of bytes would be greater than real quantity of bytes inside of *chunck_tmp* if I try evaluate it with "len(str(*chunck_tmp*))". To prove it I simulate a little test :

```
>>> test="abcde;abcde;abcde;abcde;abcde\n"
>>> len(test)
30
>>> t=test.split(';')
>>> type(t)
<type 'list'>
>>> len(str(t))
47
>>> print str(t)
['abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde', 'abcde\n']
```

Look at test has exactly **30 bytes** considering '\n' as a special character (this happens because in csv files each line has a line feed in POS-IX format or '\r\n' in WINDOWS format).

Using the expression "len(*test*)" we can check it but now if we create a list of this string test using a split and try to discover the original size after this operation we found the problem : length is **47 bytes** !!

Why ? Well, printing the chunck converted to string and evaluate its length we can see that now the 17 bytes exceed are exactly "[" (1 byte), " " (4 bytes), "'" (10 bytes), "\n" (1 byte) and "]" (1 byte).

Bingo !!! 1 + 4 + 10 + 1 + 1 = **17 bytes**

And now my point : Someone can help me to find out a way to calculate the real value of bytes inside of *list object* in Python ? My real intention is use to know the real size returned by function *readlines* after call it passing an argument as showed belong represented by *chunck_tmp*.

Comment: What do you mean by "real value of bytes inside of list object"?  You want to know the size of each `str` object, including its header information as well as its array of characters? Or just how many bytes are in the array of characters? (I'm also confused by whether you want to count a `\r\n` that was translated to `\r` as 2 bytes or 1.)

Comment: Why are you even doing this? Read e.g. http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/readlines-considered-silly.html?m=1

Comment: Meanwhile, the brackets, commas, and spaces aren't stored in memory at all; they're just generated on the fly when you ask a list for its `str` or `repr` representation to print it out, and I don't think they have anything to do with anything you want (although I could be wrong, because I don't understand what you want).

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Actually, `readlines(n)` can be useful, it's just `readlines()` that can't. (And I hope I said so somewhere in that post… Checking, I did, although my best example involved partializing readlines with 8192 to map over a pool, which is kind of a stretch…) Anyway, iterating a line at a time, I _think_ he'd still have whatever issue it is he's having (knowing about newline translation, or `len(repr(s))` vs `len(s)`, or whatever it is)…

Comment: @abarnert I hadn't realised that was you!

Comment: @abarnert: Sorry by my explanation, my point is really know the number of bytes returned by readlines after I called, so I tried to explain using an example of context inside of a list object (If I not wrong type(f.readlines(k)) = list, no ?!)

Comment: @abarnet: You're right ! BTW I read your post in blog but I can't get the result of bytes of readlines returned.

Comment: So you want the number of bytes in the strings returned by `readlines` (not the number of bytes read off disk, or how much space the list takes in memory, or the length of the string representation, or anything else)? That's just the first comment by @jonrsharpe then.

Comment: @abarnert: The result of sum(map(len, t)) = 26. Why is different of len(test) ?

Comment: @JulioFonseca: Because, unlike `readlines`, `split` removes the `;` delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're getting confused between the actual objects, and their string representations:

> The problem is that now the information has another format including spaces, brackets and something else …

This is wrong. The information is not in another format including spaces, brackets, and something else; it's just a list of strings.

If you call `str` on a list of strings, it will generate spaces, brackets, and commas, and quotes around each string, and possibly convert some characters to backslash escapes, and so on. But there's no reason to call `str` here.

If you want the sum of the lengths of all of the strings in a list of strings, just write that:

```
sum(map(len, chunck_tmp))
```

---

Now, this may not be the same as the number of bytes actually read off-disk. As you pointed out, there may be Windows-style newlines (`\r\n`) that get converted to Python-style newlines (`\n`). But this will only happen if you've opened the file in universal newlines mode (e.g., mode `'rU'` instead of `'r'`).

If that's what you're trying to solve, you can fix it by looking at the `newlines` attribute of the file. If it was Windows-style, that will be `'\r\n'`. So, you can do this:

```
sum(map(len, chunck_tmp)) + len(chunck_tmp) * (len(f.newlines) - 1)
```

But again, `sum(map(len, chunck_tmp))` is *already* the number of bytes *in the list*, which is what you asked for; this is only if you want to get *the number of bytes on disk that had to be read to generate this list*, which is a different thing.

---

Finally, in attempting to figure out what was going on, you tried to simplify it by just calling `split` on a string. But there's a big difference here: `readlines` leaves the newlines on the end of each line, but `split` throws away the delimiters. Still, the answer is nearly the same as the last point:

```
sum(map(len, t)) + (len(t) - 1) * len(';')
```

(Obviously in your case, you know `len(';')` is 1, and multiplying by 1 does nothing, so you can leave it off.)

But, once again, `sum(map(len, t))` is already the length of bytes in the list, which is what you asked for; you only need this if you want to regenerate the length of the original `test`.

Comment: @abarnet: Thanks for your explanation ! I think that my case is almost done. When I try "*sum(map(len,t))*" the value returned (26 bytes) is sum all strings and "*\n*" character. So, I need to sum all the semicolons too, and this way I'll find the number I need (30 bytes).

Comment: @abarnet: **Great !!!** This is exactly was I expected. Is possible replicated it in case of *readlines(k)* ? Anyway you salved my skin with my appointments.

Comment: @JulioFonseca: I don't understand your last comment. Unlike `split`, `readlines(k)` doesn't remove any bytes (except for the converting-Windows-to-Python if you opened the file in universal-newlines mode), as explained in the answer.

Comment: Thank you a lot, guys (*abarnert* and *johnrsharpe*) !!! I finish my tests and the explanation of yours completely help me a lot.